# Transfer data from sample database category table to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a database with tables below:

first table name: newsdetails.

Columns: id,description,cat_id

second table name: category.

Columns: id,name,parent_id.

Now i want to transfer this data to wordpress database.

What i know: there is a `wp_insert_post` function in wordpress to insert posts in database.

There is a parameter `'post_category' => [ array(<category id>, <...>) ] //Add some categories.`

This function associate a post to a particular category.

What i have right now is the categories available from the old table. Even if i provide that categories in this parameter, there is no such categories created in the wordpress database.

How can i create categories in the wordpress based upon existing categories table so that my new posts will now be associated with the new categories?

Answer (score 0):

Register category like this:

```
$category = array('cat_name' => 'My Category', 'category_description' => 'A Cool Category', 'category_nicename' => 'category-slug', 'category_parent' => '');

$cat_id = wp_insert_category($category, true);
```

and then use **$cat_id** inside that array, will work.

More information in [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category)